# How to fetch multiple maximum records from the same column?

Tags: mysql, group-by, subquery, fetch

I am using mysql db.

sbs=> select * from docbodyversion;

```
 bodyid | internaldocid | versionid
--------+---------------+-----------
   1121 |          1245 |         1
   1122 |          1245 |         2
   1124 |          1246 |         1
   1125 |          1246 |         2
   1126 |          1246 |         3
```

I want to write such a query so that o/p will be like this-:

```
 bodyid | internaldocid | versionid
--------+---------------+-----------
   1122 |          1245 |         2
   1126 |          1246 |         3
```

So I want only max versionid of each record....

Can anybody plz guide me??

Comment: Please put name of the database and version of it in tags.

Comment: [Here is the link to a very helpful article](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT MAX(bodyId) AS BodyID,internaldocid, MAX(versionid) AS VersionID 
FROM docbodyversion GROUP BY internaldocid
```

[SEE THIS FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a157/1)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select d.*
from docbodyversion d
join
    (select internaldocid,MAX(versionid) as versionid
     from docbodyversion
     group by internaldocid)a
on a.versionid=d.versionid
and a.internaldocid=d.internaldocid
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
SELECT DISTINCT BT.BODY_ID, A.INTERNAL_DOC_ID, A.VERSION_ID
  FROM SO_BUFFER_TABLE_16 BT,
       (SELECT DISTINCT BT.INTERNAL_DOC_ID, MAX(BT.VERSION_ID) VERSION_ID
          FROM SO_BUFFER_TABLE_16 BT
         GROUP BY BT.INTERNAL_DOC_ID) A
 WHERE BT.VERSION_ID = A.VERSION_ID
   AND BT.INTERNAL_DOC_ID = A.INTERNAL_DOC_ID
```